# Drupal : Display time remaining instead of expired date

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

In drupal, I enabled Date module and added Date (Unix timestamp) to a content type, my question is instead of display the date how do I display the remaining time?

Highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [format_interval](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_interval/7)() function.

You can put the following code in your theme's template.php file:

```
function [YOUR_THEME]_ago($timestamp)
{
    $ago = format_interval((time() - $timestamp) , 2) . t(' ago');
    return $ago;
}
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

[Countdown](http://drupal.org/project/countdown) looks promising for what you need.